# SQL Server - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        nr_CRM,
        CLASSIFIC,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY nr_CRM) AS total_cnt
    FROM tmp_usr..tb
)
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT(nr_CRM) AS CRM_total
FROM 
    cte
WHERE 
    total_cnt = 3
    AND CLASSIFIC = 'GOLD'
    AND dt_Visita >= '2021-01-25' AND dt_Visita <= '2021-02-26'
```

It was written on SQLite, but now I need to use SQL Server and it doesn't work.

On line 10, it displays the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

How can I adjust it?

Comment: `DISTINCT` isn't a function, it's an operator; it isn't followed by parentheses.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a **<set quantifier>**.

Answer (score 0):

there is an extra opening parenthesis :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        nr_CRM,
        CLASSIFIC,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY nr_CRM) as total_cnt
    FROM tmp_usr..tb
)
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT nr_CRM) AS CRM_total -- <-- here
    FROM cte
    WHERE
      total_cnt = 3
      AND CLASSIFIC = 'GOLD'
      AND dt_Visita >= '2021-01-25'
      and dt_Visita <= '2021-02-26'
```